# How to access max speed for platformer character 2d in unity?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, character

I'm trying to acces the speed and change it by javascript .
 But i receive the message error :
BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'PlatformerCharacter2D'.
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1dUH.png)

GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent(PlatformerCharacter2D).maxSpeed=5;

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to pass a string into the GetComponent method, so it should look like this: GetComponent("PlatformerCharacter2D")

Comment: i already tried this and naming my string to any wrong value just ignore the message error and give me a new one : BCE0019: 'maxSpeed' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.

Comment: Make sure that the maxSpeed property is publicly accessible, if it is make sure you spelling is correct with capitalisation.

Comment: how to make sure it is publicly accessible ?

Comment: Look at the PlatformerCharacter2D class code, and take a look the porperties in that  class.

Comment: making another string in the getComponent method is not working at all . i tried another exemple that worked before , and this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use 
`GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>().maxSpeed=5;`.